# Why does python use identation instead of braces and keywords?

Tags: python

One thing I was never able to wrap my head around is why python uses indentation unlike other scripting languages. Being dependent on indentation makes editing python codes sometimes very frustrating.

ps. I have a strong feeling that this question gets closed for not being constructive. As much as I think the answer would be very interesting to know.

Comment: Well for one it's more readable. And you'll spend more time reading code than writing it.

Comment: If you have a strong feeling the question will be closed, why ask it at all?

Comment: because I still believe it is good to know the reason, but there are some users that have very strict understanding of what is constructive and what is not. :)

Comment: you could always do `from __future__ import braces`

Comment: @ipluto: Sure, it's something interesting to know; that doesn't mean it's a question for StackOverflow. It's also interesting and useful to know why some people like Haskell better than Python, what libraries people like for implementing binary search trees in Python and why, why Ruby is called Ruby, or what's the fastest route to get from my house to the airport by bicycle, but those aren't appropriate questions for SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer you want is well written in the doc, and I can't summarize this better than by quoting the text:

### [Why does Python use indentation for grouping of statements?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html)

> Guido van Rossum believes that using indentation for grouping is extremely elegant and contributes a lot to the clarity of the average Python program. Most people learn to love this feature after a while.
>
> Since there are no begin/end brackets there cannot be a disagreement between grouping perceived by the parser and the human reader. Occasionally C programmers will encounter a fragment of code like this:
>
> ```
> if (x <= y)
>         x++;
>         y--;
> z++;
> ```
>
> Only the `x++` statement is executed if the condition is true, but the indentation leads you to believe otherwise. Even experienced C programmers will sometimes stare at it a long time wondering why `y` is being decremented even for `x > y`.
>
> Because there are no begin/end brackets, Python is much less prone to coding-style conflicts. In C there are many different ways to place the braces. If you’re used to reading and writing code that uses one style, you will feel at least slightly uneasy when reading (or being required to write) another style.
>
> Many coding styles place begin/end brackets on a line by themselves. This makes programs considerably longer and wastes valuable screen space, making it harder to get a good overview of a program. Ideally, a function should fit on one screen (say, 20-30 lines). 20 lines of Python can do a lot more work than 20 lines of C. This is not solely due to the lack of begin/end brackets – the lack of declarations and the high-level data types are also responsible – but the indentation-based syntax certainly helps.

Comment: This is a very interesting piece that I haven't seen before. Thanks for sharing. So basically, readability is guaranteed at the price of the programmer's extra effort while developing.

Comment: @ipluto: No, readability is guaranteed with the benefit of _less_ programmer effort while developing. You use the exact same indentation you'd use in C, but you don't type the braces. Fewer keystrokes, fewer places to make mistakes, fewer things for your or your editor to check… It _does_ mean you need an editor that isn't too horribly crappy, but you really need that anyway for coding.